# Merge multible rows into one

Tags: t-sql

I'm trying to merge multiple rows into one

First some test data

```
declare @Customers table
(
  CustomerID  varchar(200),
  SubscriptionId  varchar(200),
  OpusNr  varchar(200),
  LineType varchar(1),
  ProductFrame varchar(200),      
  Frame varchar(200),      
  ProductLeftLens varchar(200),
  LeftLens varchar(200),
  ProductRightLens varchar(200),
  RightLens varchar(200)
);


insert into @Customers values ('17762697', '270387', '6214005562', 'F', '304', 'GG0550O/006/5316/140', '304', 'Variview Standard M 1.6 70/75', '304', 'Variview Standard M 1.6 70/75')
insert into @Customers values ('17762697', '270387', '6214005562', 'L', '101', 'GG0550O/006/5316/140', '101', 'Variview Standard M 1.6 70/75', '101', 'Variview Standard M 1.6 70/75')
insert into @Customers values ('17762697', '270387', '6214005562', 'R', '303', 'GG0550O/006/5316/140', '303', 'Variview Standard M 1.6 70/75', '303', 'Variview Standard M 1.6 70/75')
```

And the result

[image]

I would like the rows merged into one

if LineType = 'F' then I want the value from ProductFrame  and Frame
if LineType = 'L' then I want the value from ProductLeftLens
and  LeftLens
if LineType = 'R' then I want the value from ProductRightLens and  RightLens

Here I've done the Merge by hand on my DemoData

[image]

Is is on a SQL server 2017

Comment: `MAX` and a `CASE` expression? Though all those rows have the same value, so why not just `MAX`?

Comment: @Larnu you're right, it would work on the given example. But I've just noticed I've left out some important stuff in ny test data. 

Hangon 5 min . I'll update the question

Comment: Question updated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
SELECT 
  CustomerID,
  SubscriptionId   = MAX(c.SubscriptionId),
  OpusNr           = MAX(c.OpusNr),
  ProductFrame     = MAX(CASE c.LineType WHEN 'F' THEN c.ProductFrame END),
  Frame            = MAX(c.Frame),
  ProductLeftLens  = MAX(CASE c.LineType WHEN 'L' THEN c.ProductLeftLens END),
  LeftLens         = MAX(c.LeftLens),
  ProductRightLens = MAX(CASE c.LineType WHEN 'L' THEN c.ProductRightLens END),
  RightLens        = MAX(c.RightLens)
FROM     @Customers AS c
GROUP BY c.CustomerID, c.SubscriptionId , c.OpusNr;
```

Returns:

```
CustomerID   SubscriptionId   OpusNr        ProductFrame  Frame                  ProductLeftLens   LeftLens                        ProductRightLens    RightLens
------------ ---------------- ------------- ------------- ---------------------- ----------------- ------------------------------- ------------------- ---------------------------------
17762697     270387           6214005562    304           GG0550O/006/5316/140   101               Variview Standard M 1.6 70/75   101                 Variview Standard M 1.6 70/75
```